# DOSBox-X application works if started in the same directory as the binary, but not from elsewhere

Tags: macos

I have an Application created years ago in a DOS environment.

I used DOSBox-X to install it in the Mac and it works fine if I access it through the terminal.

In the process of creating an install for this application (using packages) I also created a desktop icon (using bristow in a post-install script) and a dock link (using emmett in a post-install script).

Both those links are created and have the right Original location, including the name of the DOSBox-X command to start the application.

My problem is that the links do not work. The app seems to start then crashes. I have examined the permissions for various folders that are used and they are fine (the application does start fine from the terminal).

To start the application from the terminal I cd to its folder, `/Applications/CandatAp` and execute the command `./candatbox` and it works.
but if I am not in the CandatAp folder and I execute `/Applications/CandatAp/candatbox` it crashes.

I want the application to be simple for the end user. I just want them to either click on the desktop icon or click on the icon in the dock.
I believe I need those icons to change to the folder before executing the command.

Any suggestions on how to do that? I have spent the last few days looking for scripts and most of the solutions say "first start up the terminal then…" which is what I do not want my user to do.

Mac mini, High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: While system specs are useful, the title of a question should summarise the content of the question. I've edited the title but feel free to [edit] further, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for that, future questions will take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept on working on this and found a way to start the application from the folder. There was an option in the configuration file of dosbox to set the target directory to the program's directory.
That worked.